# mvc5: Cannot access a disposed object. asp.net mvc5 using unity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

im using vs 2013, mvc5 and ef6 + unity.mvc5:
my account controller class has this constructor:

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.UserManager = userManager;
    }
```

and this is my unity config:

```
    container.RegisterType(typeof(AccountController),
            new InjectionConstructor(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>())));
```

when i try to register a new user i get this exception:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'UserManager`1'.
```

on this line of code and register action:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

when i remove unity and set dependecy resolver to default it works just fine.
i`v tried many unity configs but didnt work...
thanks alot for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution, changed the unity config to this:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, 
            UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT create a parameterless constructor, (I can't vote it down as I don't have enough reputation), that answer totally avoids IoC and instead tries to build up the object by knowing the entire dependency hierarchy for the object, i.e. AccountController needs to know that it has a dependency on UserStore and it needs to know that Userstore has a dependency on UserContext. This is exactly what DI containers are there to avoid!

It is hard to provide you with an exact answer as there is a lot of your code missing.

One thing that looks odd to me is that you have an uppercase `UserManger`, that usually means that you are using it as a type, not referencing a local private variable. Can you show me the rest of the code?

Also, I would question why you are not referencing everything via Interfaces. That is by far the preferred way to set up proper DI.

I will try to knock up some test code that shows what I would do and then post this here, if you could answer those questions in the meantime that would be great.

Cheers Mike

Comment: UserManager is a public property no my account controller thats why its uppercase.

Comment: Why is it public? Will anything else ever access it via the controller?

Comment: Im using visual studio 2013 and they just made it. and btw i didnt change it.

Comment: OK, I see what you are tying to do now. I had turned authentication off for my example hence I didn't see the same as you. I really cannot see why that property is public, if you change it to private it still compiles perfectly.

Comment: yeah, i just forgot to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

In your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IUserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public HomeController(IUserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = "user";
        var password = "password";

        var result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Interface for UserManager

```
public interface IUserManager<T> where T : ApplicationUser
{
    int CreateAsync(string user, string password);
}
```

Actual UserManager class

```
public class UserManager<T> : IUserManager<T> where T : ApplicationUser
{
    private IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore;

    public UserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore)
    {
        this.userStore = userStore;
    }

    public int CreateAsync(string user, string password)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Interface for UserStore

```
public interface IUserStore<T> where T : ApplicationUser
{
}
```

Actual UserStore

```
public class UserStore<T> : IUserStore<T> where T : ApplicationUser
{
}
```

Unity configuration

```
container.RegisterType(typeof (IUserManager<>), typeof (UserManager<>));
container.RegisterType(typeof (IUserStore<>), typeof (UserStore<>));
```

Hope this helps.

There is obviously lots that is not the same as your app, i.e. not doing the method call async, not reading the password in from the model, etc. but it should give an idea of how to solve the problem that you outlined.

This solution will give you proper constructor dependency injection, which will allow you to have all of your configuration in one place (i.e. the container config) and it will give you interfaces in your constructors which will make it much easier for you to mock those dependencies in your unit tests.

Cheers Mike